# Why is jQuery's append redrawing my Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a function that increases the date by one day every second. When the date is equal to certain dates I want to fill my #newsDiv with additional text. The #newsDiv will show all past "news." The #newsDiv will scroll so the div doesn't get too big. However, whenever new "news" is added to my div the size increase, and the border becomes redrawn.

```
var dateCheck = function () {
    switch (dString) {
    case "January 1, 1992":
        $('#newsDiv').append(dString + "<br>"//bunch of other code);
        break;
    case "January 2, 1992":
        $('#newsDiv').append(dString + "<br>" //bunch of other code);
        break;
    case "January 3, 1992":
        $('#newsDiv').append(dString + "<br>" //bunch of other code);
        break;
    case "January 4, 1992":
        $('#newsDiv').append(dString + "<br>" //bunch of other code);
        break;
}
};
```

fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/xbbmtxug/

Comment: Why are you using a switch to *do the same thing in every case*? Assign/update the `coalBonus` variable in the switch, do the `append()` *afterwards*.

Comment: I stripped out a lot of my code for the question because as the dates change many of variables also change. I would of had to put a lot more code into my fiddle that really doesn't affect my current problem. I just forgot to remove the coalBonus variable.

Comment: In your fiddle you're using `<span>` tags, not `<div>` tags.  `<span>` is an inline element, you should be using a block element `<div>`  See if this helps:  http://jsfiddle.net/xbbmtxug/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default `span` elements are displayed `inline`.

Either make `#newsContainer` a `div`, or change its display to either `block` or `inline-block`.

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/uqqqkhha/)